# File in Shiny docker image do not change if I change that file in host

Tags: docker, shiny, shinyapps

I have created a Docker image of my shiny app in my Ubuntu machine.

This App usees few files placed in some folder in Host (not within the container). I keep them outside of the container as they are large in size.

Now I run below code to get my image up and running

```
docker run -d -v /opt/lampp/htdocs/www:/www:rw --restart=always -d -p 8383:8383 app
```

With this I was expecting that if I make any change to any file in `'/opt/lampp/htdocs/www'` in Host then that would automatically refect in the `www` folder within the container.

But this is not happening. Why is it so? Do I need to rebuild the image of my App every time I change any file in `'/opt/lampp/htdocs/www'` in host?

I also tried to copy files directly from host to container as below, but still dont see any change reflected in the docker image of my shiny app

```
docker exec -i 9498f0e1c5066f060c0e9439faa744cc39208ee27fc0dbe0d54075c683748137 bash -c 'cat > /www/aaa.csv' < /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/aaa.csv
```

Comment: What makes you think the changes to your host files are not reflected in your container bind mount ? There's nothing wrong with your command (except the copy attempt at the end which is unnecessary and will fail). Test with something simple: run a container, on your host `touch /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/imhere.txt`, then `docker exec <yourcontainer> ls -l /www`. You should see the `imhere.txt` file. If this is the case (I'm 99.9% sure it is unless you are connecting to a remote dockerd), figure out what is your real problem. (my2cent: you application in container is not picking up the changes).

Comment: I had a line of code in server.R file which reads the csv file as read.csv('www/aaa.csv'), which was giving trouble. I changed this to read.csv('/www/aaa.csv') - and everything is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your copy will not work since all what comes after your `exec` command refering to files in container.

you should use :

```
docker cp /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/aaa.csv YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME:/www/aaa.csv
```

I really do not know why your mount not working , do you see anything in logs ?

finally you could remove the first `-d` from your `docker run`command